# How to read from a file within a project?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm working on a homework assignment and I cannot seem to read from a file in my project.

Here's a screenshot of the project since it's a little easier than trying to type out the whole file structure of it:

[image]

FileScanner is just a class the professor provided that basically encapsulates the Scanner object. Constructor requires  path to a file. When I try to run this, I get an error saying the file does not exist.

I'm running Windows, I've tried both a forward slash or two backslashes in the path but neither work. I'm not sure which I should use because I think the professor is grading them on Linux. But either way, can't get it working locally. How are you supposed to reference a local file?

```
FileScanner fs = new FileScanner("data/file00.game");
FileScanner fs = new FileScanner("data\\file00.game");
FileScanner fs = new FileScanner("..\\data\\file00.game");
```

Neither seem to be valid paths. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably assuming the wrong base folder. You are using relative path but relative to what? Try doing new `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath())` to see where you are and where you should put your files.

I am pretty sure if you change your path to `../../data/` it would work.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the file does not exist within the execution context of the application when it is run.

Try using something like...

```
System.out.println(new File("data/file00.game").exists());
```

to see if the file exists relative to where it is begin executed.

Comment: Nothing says the data files are in the class path. If OP wants to use them that way, has to make sure that they are.

Comment: @user3001267 That would also be my assumption, once I was able to take a closer look at the image

Comment: I get a false if I try to print that out, so somehow it's just totally not seeing the file.

Comment: Where the program is begin executed is not the same place where the data is stored use `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath())` (stolen from @user3001267) to see where your program is being executed.  You may need to either move the `data` folder or change the execution context

Comment: @MadProgrammer The way OP assessing file looks correct. My assumption is it has to do something with `FileScanner` class which looks custom to me.